# Windows Mail unable to send after stalling pop server

Tags: windows-7, email, pop3, windows-mail

I have 2 users that are unable to send email through their Windows Mail (Win 7).

One user exceeded our daily email limit and exceeded the number of recipients limit, and the other send many large (LARGE) images in one email.

I have checked with the web host, and they checked the pop servers for me, and everything appeared to be fine with both accounts.

However, both users who were able to send emails up until this point, can no longer send messages.

I'm assuming it's a stall in Windows Mail somewhere, but how would I clear it?

thanks!

Comment: Please define `can no longer send messages`. Do they get an error message? Do their messages bounce? Something else?

Comment: @PeeHaa - nothing happens - no error message, no bounce

Answer (score 1):

You will want to move the messages out of the outbox then try to send a test message. If the test message does not go though you may want to repair Windows live mail.

See http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/42715.aspx For instructions on repairing windows live mail.